# What's the difference between growth rate of single entity of a population vs growth rate of entire population?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

Let's assume I have a logistic model modelling the population of humans.

$$dP/dt = r*P(k-P)$$

What's the difference between the growth rate of a **single human** and the growth rate of the **entire population**?

I assumed when the question mentioned single human, they meant let P = 1.

So in this case logically it would be 0, as it takes at least 2 humans to reproduce.

Just to confirm. Is that what it means for a growth rate of a single entity vs the growth rate of the entire population?